# Node red TCP close connection

Tags: tcp, node-red

i am trying to communicate with external controller by TCP protocol. For this i installed tcp clien (node-red-contrib-tcp-client) where i need to firstly send parameters and then listen till not receive specific value, then close connection and again wait till get trigger for sent again parameter. Listening works fine, but i have problem to close connection and seems that "Close" command not work, have anybody same issue?

[TCP client library](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-tcp-client)

```
[
{
    "id": "107841736addae4f",
    "type": "tcp-client",
    "z": "f763f4cf2bc74268",
    "action": "payload",
    "actionType": "msg",
    "host": "10.13.4.231",
    "hostType": "str",
    "port": "33",
    "portType": "str",
    "datamode": "stream",
    "datatype": "buffer",
    "newline": "",
    "xmlAttrkey": "$",
    "xmlCharkey": "_",
    "xmlStrip": false,
    "xmlArray": false,
    "xmlNormalizeTags": false,
    "xmlNormalize": false,
    "write": "payload",
    "writeType": "msg",
    "topic": "",
    "name": "",
    "debug": "none",
    "x": 450,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": [
        [
            "de03186be168a022"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "13130ae434a02cbe",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "f763f4cf2bc74268",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "Listen",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 110,
    "y": 320,
    "wires": [
        [
            "107841736addae4f"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "f2da28789b81f6bc",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "f763f4cf2bc74268",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "Close",
    "payload": "Close",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "x": 130,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": [
        [
            "107841736addae4f"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "de03186be168a022",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "f763f4cf2bc74268",
    "name": "debug 3",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 820,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": []
}
```

]